# Having some PHP Pagination issues

Tags: php, mysqli

New to PHP and can't really figure out how to get a pagination to work with my current code:

```
 <?php
    if($result = $db ->query("SELECT * FROM twentyfour ORDER BY date DESC")) {
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table><tr><th>Category</th><th>Date</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th></tr>";

            while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                echo '<tr><td>', $row->category, '</td><td>', $row->date = date('jS F Y',strtotime($row->date)), '<td>', $row->name, '<td>', $row->location, '</td></td></td></tr>';
            }
            echo "</table>";

            $result->free();

        }

    }

    ?>
```

I've tried multiple examples to try and work it into my code but I'm not good with this.

I tried this: http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Numbered-Pagination-Using-MySQLi
However replacing the top with:

```
$News = $db ->query("SELECT * FROM twentyfour");
$maxRows_News =2;

$NewsTotal = $db->query("SELECT count(1) a FROM twentyfour");
$News_Total = (int)$NewsTotal->Results[0]['a'];
$Req_pages = ceil($NewsTotal/$maxRows_News);

$totalRows_News = $News_Total;
```

I've come up with this from watching a video:

```
    <?php
$per_page = 2;

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM twentyfour ORDER BY id"))
{
    if ($result->num_rows != 0)
    {
      $total_results = $result->num_rows;
      $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

      if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
      {
        $show_page = $GET['page'];

        if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
        {
$start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
$end = $start + $per_page;
        }
        else 
        {
         $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;    
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;
      }

// display pagination
      echo "<p><a href='view.php'>View All</a> | <b>View Page: </b>";
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
      {
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
        {
            echo $i . " ";
        }
        else {
            echo "<a href='update.php?page=$i'>" . $i . "</a> ";
        }
      }
         echo "</p>";

         // display records
 for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
 {
    if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

 }
            $row = $result->fetch_object();

            echo '<tr><td>', $row->category, '</td><td>', $row->date = date('jS F Y',strtotime($row->date)), '<td>', $row->name, '<td>', $row->location, '</td></td></td></tr>';

    }
        else
        {
            echo "No results!";
        }
}
else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}




?>
```

Comment: You're not passing in a starting index value in the request...so obviously this is not going to work.

Comment: The other things is, if you have numeric indexes in the mysql table, use them: it will make pagination extremely easy, and you won't be reading the whole table each time which is a waste.

Comment: If you do a quick google search you'll come up with dozens of tutorials on how to paginate mysql results with php.

Comment: Added to the post with another script, data displays (1 line of it) but won't change upon clicking links. I am actually very new to this so I have no clue what I'm really doing or what half this stuff means, trying my best to laern though.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple piece of code that does something with pagination.

```
$total = 1000; //Or do something like SELECT COUNT(*) AS a FROM table
$itemsPerPage = 30;

$numberOfPages = ceil($total/$itemsPerPage);
echo $numberOfPages; //output: 34

//Use the GET url to check which page must be opened.. else it's always 1;
$pageToOpen = is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
echo $pageToOpen; //output: 1 (or something else if you define ?page=XXX to your url)

//Query to fetch results from database
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT " . (($pageToOpen-1) * $itemsPerPage) . ", " .     $itemsPerPage;
echo $sqlQuery; //SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 30 when page is one.. SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 420, 30 when page is 15.. etc
```